# Show composition/aggregation/association relations between objects in Visual Paradigm UML diagrams?

Tags: php, oop, uml, diagrams, visual-paradigm

I have Netbeans installed with Visual Paradigm plugin.

I have converted my php code into UML diagrams (modeling -> instant reverse). I can see relations (drawn lines) between superclass and subclasses. However, i cannot see relations between objects inside objects (composition/aggregation/association)?

The code looks like:

```
class Thread {
    private $tag = '';

    public function __construct($tagObject) {
         $this->tag = $tagObject;
    }
}
```

I know its possible using Java cause i've read about it.

Im using PHP, is this still possible?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that plugin, but you probably need to add type hinting for it to work.

```
public function __construct(Tag $tagObject) { /*...*/ }
```